# Invalid column name 'Shop_Name' Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a dropdown based on the selection made in the dropdown I populate a list of checkbox.

```
        protected void dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection Mcon = new SqlConnection(MA);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select distinct Shop_Name from prod.dbo.Dim_Shop f INNER JOIN Dim_Warehouse p on p.Warehouse_key = f.Warehouse_Key where p.Warehouse_DB_Name=" + this.dropdown.SelectedValue, Mcon);
        SqlDataAdapter dataAadpter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAadpter.Fill(ds);
        CheckBoxList1.DataSource = ds;
        CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "Shop_Name";
        CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
    }
```

When I run this I get Invalid Column name error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I guess obvious question is - do you have a column named "Shop_Name" in the Dim_Shop table in your database?

Comment: @ HitLikeAHammer: Thank you. @Sudhakar Tillapudi has answered it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** you have not enclosed single quotes properly  providing `this.dropdown.SelectedValue` parameter in your `SELECT` query.

**Solution :** you need to enclose `VARCHAR` types in single quotes properly.

Try This:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select distinct Shop_Name from prod.dbo.Dim_Shop f INNER JOIN Dim_Warehouse p on p.Warehouse_key = f.Warehouse_Key where p.Warehouse_DB_Name='" + this.dropdown.SelectedValue+"'", Mcon);
```

Your `Query` is open to sql `injection attacks` , please use `parameterised queries` to avoid them.

With parameterised query:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select distinct Shop_Name from prod.dbo.Dim_Shop f INNER JOIN Dim_Warehouse p on p.Warehouse_key = f.Warehouse_Key where p.Warehouse_DB_Name=@name", Mcon);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",this.dropdown.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: Why do you think the error the OP received would be solved by your fix?

Comment: Sudhakar Tillapudi: Thank you so much. Its fixed :)

Comment: @Sudhakar Tillapudi: Sure I will.

Comment: @KirkWoll : because OP has not properly enclosed  `this.dropdown.SelectedValue` parameter in his `SELECT` query.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi, sure, I was just surprised it resulted in that particular error message.  But since it sounds like you solved the problem for the OP, I guess it was right. :)

Comment: @KirkWoll : yes asper title `Invalid column name 'Shop_Name' Error` it  sounds like there is really a cloumn missing in table(in database) or something else :)